# Unique Membership Configuration/Tiers

Tags: civimember

New to CiviCRM and I'm trying to understand the best way to configure some unique memberships requirements for an organization.

The organization has the following types of memberships:
**Individual - US Domestic** - $125/yr
**Individual - International** - $145/yr

**Institutional** - $425/yr (max 4 members, then +$125 for each member over 4)

What would be the best way to configure and manage this in CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

Welcom. Do the first 2 either as different Memb Types, or as Price Set options.

For the latter do you want the related contacts data in civicrm or not?

Either should be possible out of the box. If you do want their data then you should use Related Contacts. How you approach it in terms of the form will depend on your CMS.

if this was Drupal I would expect it can all be achieved via Webform. Hmm less certain how to do this in pure civicrm if you need all the related contact details without jumping through a few hoops (eg using several forms)

Comment: Thank you for the input! I have CiviCRM installed on a subdomain on wordpress. Public facing site it on the primary domain aslo on wordpress. I'd like to see about integrating/automating/linking the two possibly down the road so I'm trying to think about how to set it up now to avoid having to completely rework it down the road.